# Simple .htaccess Rewrite of a Param

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get a param to rewrite to a directory, nothing is happening.

Example of what I want:

Rewrite From: http://domain.com/results.php?s=abc

Rewrite To: http://domain.com/results/abc

This is what I have, there is a www redirect to non-www, and that part is working fine, but my param rewrite is doing nothing.

I'm on Apache 2.4.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^results/([^/]*)$ /results.php?c=$1 [L]
```

Ideas? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+results\.php\?c=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /results/%1? [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^results/([^/]+)/?$ results.php?c=$1 [L,QSA]
```